# jmeter not launching showing integer expression expected issue

Tags: jmeter

showing this error when i tap on jmeter from the bin folder in mac :

```sh
bash: export: `home]': not a valid identifier
shubhams-MacBook-Pro:~ shubhamsaini$ /Users/hell/Downloads/apache-jmeter-5.1/bin/jmeter ; exit;
/Users/hell/Downloads/apache-jmeter-5.1/bin/jmeter: line 128: [: : integer expression expected
/Users/hell/Downloads/apache-jmeter-5.1/bin/jmeter: line 192: [path/bin/java: No such file or directory
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can run JMeter by "tapping"

1. Make sure you have [Java Runtime Environment version 8 or higher](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html) for Mac installed

   [image]
2. Once you install Java verify that it can be used by launching [Terminal application](https://macpaw.com/how-to/use-terminal-on-mac) and typing the following command:

   ```
   java --version
   ```

   you should see installed Java version as the output
3. Assuming step 2 success:

   - navigate to JMeter's bin folder:

     ```
     cd /Users/hell/Downloads/apache-jmeter-5.1/bin/
     ```
   - launch JMeter:

     ```
     ./jmeter.sh
     ```
4. That's it, you should see JMeter GUI.
5. You might also be interested in [configuring your MacOS to open JMeter's JMX files on double click](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-open-jmx-files-on-a-mac-in-1-double-click/) guide

Comment: showing this error when i'm following the process you told me about.   https://ibb.co/74PmFwx

Comment: it worked, my JAVA_HOME path was incorrect that's why jmeter was unable to launch